# Windows service permission to read shared folder

Tags: .net, windows, permissions, service

I'm trying to run a windows service that reads a file in a shared folder in another server. The problem is that the computer where the service runs is in a different domain (say DomainA) than the computer where the folder is shared (say DomainB). If I go to the computer in DomainB, I can't assign permissions to users in DomainA, because it's not listed as an option. Similary, I can't run the service using an account of DomainB.

If I login into the computer in DomainA and try to open the shared folder, windows ask me for credentials and if I use some valid user in DomainB, then I can access the folder. So what I'm trying to do is to somehow pass those credentials automatically.

Do you think it's possible to do what I am trying to do? Which user should I use to run the service and what kind of permissions should I grant?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I have made this work before:

On both machines, create a local user account with the same username and password. Run your service as this account. Grant permission to reqd the required files to this account.